# Change the timeframe in strategietester programmatically

Tags: mql4

I create an Simulator for MT4. I want to change the timeframes while the tester is running. Is it possible?

Comment: What is the need to change timeframe? if you want to collect some history or indicator data from the same symbol and different timeframe - symply call other timeframes, e.g. `iClose(_Symbol,PERIOD_H1,1)` or `iMA(_Symbol,60,50,0,MODE_SMA,PRICE_CLOSE,1)`. if you want to visually see H1 while testing at a smaller - that is not supported or quite complicated, easier to open that chart as a real chart in another window

Comment: Hallo Daniel, thanks for you answer. What do you meen with quite complicated? I create a simulator to trade on weekend in historicals data in strategytester. While the tester runs, i will change the timeframe for the current chart. It es realised or not supported? Thanks

Comment: do you need visual mode of the tester? you cannot change tf in the visual mode AFAIK, maybe with period converter but not sure. if you just need a test to go without visual mode, you can access different timeframes of the same symbol from the ea itself, no need to do any other preparations

Comment: yes i need visuel mode. thanks for help